# Passing react function as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been looking around at other post but haven't found what is wrong with my code. It should pass a function down to the component as a prop, however I have dificulties accessing it as when I do I get the response that the it cannot read props of undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Props:

```
<SettingsSection    forceUpdateHandler = {this.props.forceUpdateHandler}
                                        languages = {this.props.languages}
                                        setLanguage = {this.props.setLanguage}
                                        getLanguage = {this.props.getLanguage}
                                        getParameters = {this.props.getParameters}/>
```

Component:

```
class SettingsSection extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: "java"
        }
    }

    // Send change in component upwards.
    handleChange(event) {
        this.props.setLanguage(event.target.value);
    }

    // Render component.
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/*settings section will be changed later*/}
                <h5 style={{paddingTop:"20px"}}>Settings</h5>

                {/* Language drop down menu */}
                <h6 style={{paddingTop:"15px"}}>Export Language</h6>
                <select style={{paddingTop:"5px"}} onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}>
                    {this.props.languages.map(language => { return ( <option value={language}> {language} </option>)})}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS bind(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957741/reactjs-bindthis) - Your problem is at `onChange={this.handleChange}`, not when passing props.

Comment: The [React event handling docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) cover this. It's usually worth taking a spin through framework docs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is undefined in your function. Since `undefined` doesn't have any props, you can't access `.props` of it.

You need to bind it to the component in your constructor, like so:

```js
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: "java"
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    };
```